# Navigate from HOC in next.js using Router in NextJs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating an HOC for the purpose of authentication protection, I have a layout component which I want to wrap inside of the HOC, the HOC is expected to redirector navigate the user to login when he/she tries to access the pages under the said layout, however, I am unable to navigate or redirect using the built in `Router` object from Next.js.

Below is the HOC function

```
import Router from "next/router";

const withAuth = (Component) => {
  const AuthenticatedComponent = (props) => {
    const isAuthenticated = false;
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Component {...props} />;
    } else {
      Router.push("/");
      return;
    }
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};

export default withAuth;
```

And here is the wrapped layout

```
 const PrivateLayout = ({ children }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <LayoutContainer>
        <MainSection>
          <main>{children}</main>
        </MainSection>
      </LayoutContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default withAuth(PrivateLayout)();
```

I have also tried making the `withAuth` a component in order to make use of the `useRouter` hook, but it still doesn't work. Please how can I achieve the redirection in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `useRouter()` hook instead of the Router object directly

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const router = useRouter()

const withAuth = (Component) => {
  const AuthenticatedComponent = (props) => {
    const isAuthenticated = false;
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return <Component {...props} />;
    } else {
      router.push("/");
      return;
    }
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};

export default withAuth;
```